# Trying to reverse the effect of a click function is showing everything instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let me start with a quick summary of what I have to better explain this.

I'm creating a checkout page. Within that page I have three parts to it. These seperate parts are all on the same page, but I have it set to where only one section shows up at a time. The sections are:

1. Shipping Info
2. Billing Info
3. Order confirmation

So the way it is set up is that if you click to proceed to go to the next section, that part will hide and the other part will show. That works great. The issue I am having is I am trying to create a way to get back to the previous section in case the customer needs to edit information in the past section.

The code I added to try to get back to the last section is for some reason making all of the sections show up at once.

So the sections are like this:

Shipping info code, then -

```
<button class="checkoutbutton" id="btnProceedBillingInfo"> Proceed to Billing Information</button>
```

Billing info code, then -

```
<button class="checkoutbutton" id="btnPreAuthorize">Proceed to Order Confirmation</button>
```

JS

Getting to Billing info section

```
$('#btnProceedBillingInfo ').click(function () {
    $(".shippinginfocontainer").hide();
    $('.paymentinfocontainer').show("slow");
 }
```

Getting to confirm section

```
$('#btnPreAuthorize').click(function () {
    $(".checkoutprocess > div").hide();
    $('.confirmationinfocontainer').show("slow");
    $('#widebutton').show("slow");
}
```

What I tried to do to get this to work is in the html page is add the following code:

```
<input class="backInCart" id="backToShippingInfo" value="Back to Shipping Information">
```

And then add the following JS:

```
$('#backToShippingInfo').click(function () {
    $(".paymentinfocontainer").hide();
    $('.shippinginfocontainer').show("slow");
}
```

So essentially, I was just trying to reverse the process. I am using an input figure for getting going back to the section because I do not want a button to be displayed for the back link.

If this didn't make the most sense, you can view my site at buyfarbest.com to really see what I am trying to accomplish. When you click Back to Shipping info or billing info, I just want the reverse affect to take place.

Comment: Please elaborate *making all of the sections show up at once*.  Are there multiple elements with `.shippinginfocontainer`?

Comment: There are inputs in the .shippinginfocontainer. I am wanting the different sections to show and hide in reverse. Basically a back button between sections. My code is only showing one section at a time and the proceed buttons allow to move forward through the process, I want the option to go back. The code I tried adding in broke this and made all of the sections show instead of hiding 2 of the 3.

Comment: I'm unable to locate this page on your site. Please post the link

Comment: https://buyfarbest.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a syntax errors which break js execution. Missing the closing ');' on all click handlers

```
$('#backToShippingInfo').click(function () {
    $(".paymentinfocontainer").hide();
    $('.shippinginfocontainer').show("slow");
});  // <- this guy here
```

Comment: WOW, I can't believe that I didn't notice that! Thanks so much!